# app receives different push notification structure on emulator and when prod build installed on real device iOS Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification to iOS using https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging. When run-in gin emulator I receive push notification with notification object notification":{"body":"Test","title":"Test" }, however when app is built and deployed I receive same title in "app": {"alert": {"title": "test"} }

It is deployed on Apple 6 but iOS 13.

This behaviour looks similar to message["data"] ?? message however not mentioned anywhere in docs.
How should I behave? Should I add same check or it is a bug?

Also body property is missing...

[image]

Comment: some problems from my side, did you get the solution? and android/ios might be different? I will just handle real device case.

Comment: I did not get any officcial solution or explanation yet. But i can always send repetative data in data field like body for example. But this would be a bit hacky because i believe this should be handled by firebase_messaging library

Comment: this is bad bad design with different data with same source